# How to open webpage in app

Tags: cordova, button, plugins, web, hybrid-mobile-app

Im building an app and within this app I want it so when the user clicks a link to open a webpage. I want the webpage to open in-application... so in the app. How would I go about doing this? I know this requires a cordova plugin to do this. I don't want the webpage to open in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use inAppBrowser plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Then you can use this code to open the web inside the inAppBrowser and the user won't leave your app:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

On a button

```
<input type="button" value="Open"
    onClick="window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');">
```

Comment: How do I then connect this to a button so when the user clicks on the button... it'll open the browser in the tab?

Comment: The buttons in html... would i call the 'window.open'?